# Add javadoc jar to android studio version 0.8.x

Tags: java, android, jar, android-studio, javadoc

I'm trying to integrate the java doc jar file to the jar i have, so when i hover the mouse over the function you can see the comments of that specific function.

I tried to embed the doc folder in the jar file with:

```
jar uf <your_jar> doc/<your doc file
```

I tried to attach source file, but the same, no change. In eclipse i can edit the java doc build path but in android studio its a pain. Does anyone have experience this issue and have a solution ?